# Javascript - drawImage can't reduce an image below certain resolution, regardless of canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm having an issue with `drawImage()` re-sizing a loaded image below a certain width and height. The image I'm trying to re-size is 1080x1920 and I want it to be re-sized to 540x960. If I apply `drawImage()` to reduce it to 764x1358, it works. But any resolution smaller than that (on either parameter) results in the image not being displayed on the canvas.

There is definitely some correlation between the lower bounds on the resolution, because both are approximately 70.7% of the original resolution. I'm wondering if there's an inherit limit on `drawImage` but I couldn't find any specification that said so.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var image = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.canvas.width = this.width * 2;
ctx.canvas.height = this.height; 
$(image).on("load", function() {
     ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 764, 1358);

});
image.src = "test2.jpg";
```

I edited the code to show where `image` came from.

Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas from scratch</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jcanvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1920" height="1920">
        </canvas>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $("<img>").attr("src", "test2.jpg").on('load', function() {                 
                        var imgWidth, imgHeight;
                        var imageData; 
                        var image = new Image();
                        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        ctx.canvas.width = this.width * 2;
                        ctx.canvas.height = this.height; 
                        $(image).on("load", function() {
                            /* This is where the image is loaded and 
                               inserted into the canvas */
                            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 763, 1358);
                        });
                        image.src = "test2.jpg"; 

                        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,
                                this.width,
                                this.height);

                        /* This is just part of the image manipulation, 
                           bland right now */
                        var newImgData = ctx.createImageData(imageData.width,
                                imageData.height);
                        for ( var i = 0; i < newImgData.data.length; i += 4) {
                            newImgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
                            newImgData.data[i + 1] = 0; 
                            newImgData.data[i + 2] = 0; 
                            newImgData.data[i + 3] = 255;       
                        }
                       // ctx.putImageData(newImgData, imageData.width, 0);
                 });
                });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Last Edit: I found out the solution.

As it turns out, my issue was the version of JQuery I was using. I was originally just version 1, but 1.8.3 fixed everything. So, the solution is to simply change

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is not. Could you show us what `image` is? I do not have a problem re-sizing a large image to a small scale. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YqFcu/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. It's in the edit now.

Comment: Huh, that's really weird. Your example code and mine are pretty much exactly the same. I'm just trying to get a proof of concept down right now, so I don't have any other code dealing with the image, but I do have a `ctx.getImageData(...)` and `ctx.createImageData(...)` in there. That's all I can think though.

Comment: The code you have above should work, perhaps there is a problem loading the image? Could you create a fiddle with your code?